# path_provider: Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have a problem while working with pat_provider.

**Error:**
`Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value`

**Code:**

```
void main() async {
  final appDocumentDirectory =
      await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

For more, I am using the `non-nullsafety` app, Right now I want to take the path to hive. what would you advise in such a case. Or should I downgrade the path_provider version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved!** I was doing hive the old way. The program worked when I called Hive.initFlutter(), not Hive.init(). By the way,

`import 'package: hive_flutter / hive_flutter.dart';`

and

`import 'package: hive / hive.dart';`

Don't forget to import both,

**Current code:**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter(); 
  runApp(CoozinCustomerApp());
}
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as [accepted](/help/accepted-answer) instead of writing "resolved".

Answer (score 3):

Just add two lines: import **material.dart** and add **WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final appDocumentDirectory =
      await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```